# can not free memory with mpdf and symfony2

Tags: symfony, mpdf

I created a pdf file with many tables with mpdf in symfony, the application works fine, however, every time the script runs the memory is not cleared, causing increased with each run until the memory limits are esceden.

how i can force to free the memory every time the page is load?

```
$mpdf = new \mPDF('', 'letter', '13pt', '', 5, 5, 10, 5);
      $mpdf->packTableData = true;
      $stylesheetFile = './bundles/appbundle/css/main.css';
      $stylesheet = file_get_contents($stylesheetFile);
     $pdf = $this->render('AppBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
    'object'=> $object,
    'data' => $data,
    'text' => $text,

  $html = substr($pdf, strpos($pdf, '<!'));
  $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
  $response= new Response($mpdf->Output());
```

each time that script is run memory increase about 3MB and not free it when exit, only free until restart the apache server

Thaks in advance

Comment: what version of php and apache are you using? this shouldn't happen as every request is independent of the other one unless you're using something like http://phpfastcgi.github.io/

Comment: my php version is 5.6 and apache version is 2.4, and mod_fastcgi is not enabled